# Variable disappears when I log in

Tags: php, html

I have profile page where the profile is retrieved via GET.  The index file has this:

> `$profile = $_GET['profile'];`

When I log in on the profile page, the `$profile` variable disappears.  Here is the form action on the login function:

```
<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php">
```

(The `$profile` variable is separate of the login username.)

How could I make the page retain the $profile variable?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: when you say the profile variable disappeared do you mean it disappeared after the POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET and POST variables aren't preserved throughout.  Only from one page to another.  Unless, you specifically GET or POST the variables from page to page.

Set it in a session `$_SESSION['profile'] = $_GET['profile'];` and retrive it `$profile = $_SESSION['profile'];`

Here's a simple tutorial [Session in Action](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Set the variable in the first page and retrieve it in any other page.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain query string data through a form, use a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="profile" value="<?=$_REQUEST['profile'];">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `method="post"` part of a `form` does not send variables the same way as a GET.  Instead, it posts them in the background, invisible to the user.

If you wanted to keep the variable - you could do one of two things:

1. Change the `form` to `method="get"`.
2. Change the action of the `form` to `action="./index.php?profile=<?php=$profile?>"`

Answer (score 0):

The variables passed from this form is accessible only in the "index.php" page. You will be able to access it as $_POST['profile'] or $_REQUEST['profile'].

If you want to access this in all your pages you have to use session.

You need to assign the value to $_SESSION['profile'] =  $_POST['profile']. After this you will be able to use $_SESSION['profile'] in all pages. Before assigning value to $_SESSION['profile'] you need to add session_start(); to the beginning of the code.

You can use unset($_SESSION['profile']); to remove value from the session variable